# Java Heap Size amxmlc without ant

Tags: java, ant, air, mxmlc

Out of the blue my build task for compiling my AIR application has stopped working:

```
/opt/flex-sdk/bin/amxmlc \
-optimize=true \
-define+=CONFIG::DEBUG,false \
-define+=CONFIG::RELEASE,true \
src/Main.as -output bin/Main.swf

Loading configuration file /opt/flex-sdk/frameworks/air-config.xml
Error: Java heap space

make: *** [bin/Main.swf] Error 1
```

Every mention of this on the internet is only applicable to building via ANT. I know I need to increase the heap size, but have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching around all the config files, I realised that you can actually edit `/opt/flex-sdk/bin/amxmlc`, which in turn points to `/opt/flex-sdk/bin/mxmlc` (bottom of the file):

```
VMARGS="-Xmx384m -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true "

java $VMARGS $D32 $SETUP_SH_VMARGS -jar "$FLEX_HOME/lib/mxmlc.jar" +flexlib="$FLEX_HOME/frameworks" "$@"
```

As you can see, the VMARGS are directly set here to max the heap at 384m. My fix was to up this to 1024m and everything worked fine.